# Executing a stored procedure within another stored procedure and return only count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the code for ms-sqlserver

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
   EXEC SP2
   PRINT 'Done'
```

SP2 returns some records from table. But I need only the count of records returned by the SP2.  How can I do that?

Is there a way to say select count(*) from SP2 inside SP1

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: ms-sql server....

Comment: So you want to, effectively, discard (not display) the result set returned from `SP2` and get a row count of that data?

Comment: you can use insert into exec and then count the rows in the insert target.

Comment: any code snippets pls?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
create table #t_output (col1 varchar(30), col2 int, col3 int)
  insert into #t_output (col1, col2, col3)
   EXEC SP2
   select count(*) FROM #t_output
   PRINT 'Done'

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
   EXEC SP2;
   SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
   PRINT 'Done'

Comment: SELECT @@ROWCOUNT doesnot work